# Canceling AlarmManager when notification is clicked

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

i'm developing an app that uses setRepeating method to send notification and i want the app to cancel the alarm manager when the notification is clicked (not swiped)..is there a way to do that?

if not is there a way to put a button in my notification that does the same thing or i must put a button in the app it self to cancel it? thanks

this is the part where i use the intent and AlarmManager

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);
        pend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60, pend);
```

Answer (score 1):

> when the notification is clicked (not swiped)..is there a way to do
>   that?

Yes, when you issue a notification you just have to add your alarm id to your pending intent:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationsLandingActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("alarm_id","123");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
```

Then, you can fetch that id from `savedInstanceState` from the activity that's launched:

```
public class NotificationsLandingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            String alarmId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("alarm_id");
            //cancel the alarm
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand how is this gonna affect the notification click? i'm beginner in android..i added the intent part of my code

Comment: also i have another issue if you can help this is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456093/how-to-check-if-alarmmanager-is-already-working
thanks for your time