# How to check if AlarmManager is already working?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

This qustion has been asked alot and i tried alot of the answer and didn't work so this is the most common one

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this ,0,
                    new Intent(MainActivity.this,Notifications.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

            if (alarmUp)
            {
                 am.cancel(pend);
                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Notifications.class);
                final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
                if (pendingIntent != null) {
                    pendingIntent.cancel();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Tweak cleared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"There is no Tweak!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

this button is in my MainActivity and everytime it's pressed i want to check if there is an alarm or no then if there is cancel the alarm "am" and toast massage..now the app always toasts the massage in the else statement "There is no Tweak!" even if there is alarm..i'm beginner in android so would appreciate any help..thanks.

edit

this is another button in my MainActivity that starts the alarm

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

public void onClick(View v) {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);
            pend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60, pend);
```

i press this button before i press the other one that cancels it.

edit

this is my other attempt to check for alarm and cancel it..it works but when i close the app and open it again it tells that there is not alarm "there is no tweak!" even if there is one

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (am != null && pend != null) {
                am.cancel(pend);
                pend = null;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Tweak cleared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

          else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"There is no Tweak!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    });
```

**pend and am are prviate variables which are initialized in the "start" button**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the flag "PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE", it indicates that if the described PendingIntent does not already exist, then simply return null instead of creating it.

From your code, you never created the PendingIntent before, so it will always return null.

Comment: i'm not using the same pendind intent i figured it out..thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you are not using the same pending intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
private AlarmManager mAlarmMgr;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

if (mAlarmMgr != null && mPendingIntent != null) {
    mAlarmMgr.cancel(mPendingIntent);
    mPendingIntent = null;
    Log.v("alarm", "done");
} else {
    Log.v("alarm", "no PendingIntent instance to cancel");
}
```

That's how you cancel an alarm.

Comment: thank you so much for your time i just answered it..it was silly mistake

Comment: hey i had a problem with the other method i was using so i thought i should try yours cause i find it more easy..it works good as long as i'm in the app but when i close it and go back again to cancel an alarm it tells me that there is no alarm..which i assume might be because the PendingdIntent "pend" becomes null when i close the app..i edited the question with the new code..thanks again!

Comment: You should move your alarm logic to a Service or a WakefulBroadcastReceiver that will hold a reference to your PendingIntent and AlarmManager. That will help manage the logic when scheduling an alarm (if the PendingIntent is null create one otherwise use the one you got) and the cancelling logic using the method I've posted above. Hope it helps.

Comment: i'm just beginner so i haven't worked with this class before but i already use BroadcastReceiver in the Nostifications class..i will look for it thanks.